Simple vue component returns "Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default"
Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I'm breaking some large components down into smaller components, and I've just created a component that is mostly empty like so:
<div>
  test
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {}
  }
</script>

I call it in the parent component using <my-new-component /> (which works with all other components.)
And in the parent component's script tag I have
import MyNewComponent from "path"; // everything directs correctly when I click on the component name and path in my IDE

export default {
  components: {
    MyNewComponent
  }
}

I can't get rid of the Uncaught SyntaxError: import not found: default within the MyNewComponent.vue file
This is how I'm using all my other components, what am I forgetting here? I'm on Vue 2.7

Try to wrap the divs into a <template> tag. Also consider using return in your data. Overall, also consider strongly moving to Vue3 when you can.

Thank you! Unfortunately can't move to 3 yet because it's not my project, but it's in the roadmap!

Glad it solved the issue! And good luck for the migration.

OP fixed the issue by wrapping the divs into a template tag like so
<template>
  <div>
    test
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // cool code here
    }
  }
}
</script>

Here is a reminder as of why data should return a function.

You need to wrap your HTML section in a template tag.
<template>
  <div>
    test
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {}
  }
</script>

